# Today Extension view re-adjusts itself after view appears. iOS Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, today-extension

From the storyboard, I set constraints:

1) Leading space to: Superview = 0

2) Trailing space to: Superview = 0

When today extension loads, there is this little margin offset in the beginning, then disappears after done showing the view.

[image]

Then after view-did-appear:

[image]

I tried setting "Leading space to: Superview" and "Trailing space to: Superview" to -8, -16.0 etc. But nothing worked. The offset margin showing up in the beginning still shows up to a different value as I changed the constraint value.

How can I prevent this re-adjustment from happening?

Comment: what device you are targeting?

Comment: any ios devices. The screenshot is from iPhone 6 with latest iOS version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't already do so, try adjusting your views in `viewWillAppear`. This should make sure that once the elements become visible on screen, they are already laid out correctly. I had a similar issue and this fixed it for me.